# File.Exists returns true but copying found file fails

Tags: c#

I have the following lines of code:

```
protected void MoveFilesToInBound(string filePath, string fileName, DateTime? reportingRun)
{
    var dateValue = reportingRun.Value.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
    var file = fileName + "_" + dateValue + ".csv";

    if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(filePath, file)))
    {
        File.Copy(file, InputFolder);
    }
}
```

Stepping through my code I can see that my target file is found in my target file location. However, when it comes from copying my file to my input folder (which is correct) it fails telling me: `Could not find file 'myFile_20170831.csv'`.

What's confusing me is that I don't understand why this is failing. If the file wasn't there, surely it wouldn't even reach the `File.Copy` line which is where it throws the error.

Can someone please shed some light on this? I have double and tripled checked all my locations and they do match up. I just don't get why the file isn't copying from my first location to my second.

Comment: Do you see a difference between `Path.Combine(filePath, file)` and `file`?

Comment: The copy might be failing if the file is already there.  You can add the overwrite true parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you are not using the same paths...:

```
if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(filePath, file)))
{
    File.Copy(file, InputFolder);
}
```

`Path.Combine(filePath, file)` is, hopefully, not the same as `file`. Didn't you mean to use:

```
if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(filePath, file)))
{
    File.Copy(Path.Combine(filePath, file), InputFolder);
}
```

I said "hopefully" because, if `file` was a full path ("C:\.."), `Path.Combine` would return `file` instead of the combination.

Also, in order to gain some performance, you should be using:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(filePath, file);
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
    File.Copy(filePath, InputFolder);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are checking for the existence of `Path.Combine(filePath, file)` and then you are try to copy `file` (without the path) instead. Try:

```
string fileWithPAth = Path.Combine(filePath, file);

if (File.Exists(fileWithPAth))
{
  File.Copy(fileWithPAth , InputFolder);
}
```

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, Edited.....